# DT datatable selected row color: inconsistent behavior on IE and chrome

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have an app, similar to below, which I'd like to customize the color of the selected row rendered via DT. My app code looks like below

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

bkg_shade <-"#2c3e50" 

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(HTML(paste0("table.dataTable tr.selected td, table.dataTable td.selected{background-color: ",
                        bkg_shade," !important;}"))),
  fluidRow(dataTableOutput("tbl"))
)
server <- function(input, output){
  output$tbl <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(mtcars)
  })

}

app <- shinyApp(ui = ui, server= server)
runApp(app)
```

It looks as expected on chrome, the selected row color is what I specified.
[image]

However, the selected row color is still the default color in IE.
[image]

Have anyone has experienced similar issue before? and how can I fix this so that the selected row color is also customized in IE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a very similar problem with my code and had nearly given up hope of finding a solution. However, a small tweak seems to fix it.

You'll notice the only real change is that **tbody** is inserted. You should be able to keep everything else as it is.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

bkg_shade <-"#2c3e50" 

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(HTML(paste0("table.dataTable tbody tr.selected td, table.dataTable td.selected{background-color: ", bkg_shade," !important;}"))),
  fluidRow(dataTableOutput("tbl"))
)
server <- function(input, output){
  output$tbl <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(mtcars)
  })

}

app <- shinyApp(ui = ui, server= server)
runApp(app)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering this so late on - I am sure I would have spent hours looking for the solution otherwise.