# Customising DT::datatable using css in a shiny app that uses bslib

Tags: css, r, shiny, dt, bslib

I'm trying to apply custom css styling to a DT::datatable in a shiny app. When a user selects a row in the table, I want the selected row to be yellow with black text, instead of the default blue with white text. I'm having trouble doing this successfully when also using the `bslib` package.

(A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67918769/override-dt-default-selection-color-when-using-bslib), but I couldn't make the answer work, as I will describe below).

Without `bslib`, I can successfully apply the css as follows:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(
      HTML("table.dataTable tbody tr.selected td {
             color: black !important;
             box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 9999px yellow !important;}"
      )
    )
  ),
  DT::dataTableOutput("test_table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$test_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(iris, selection = 'single')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server = server)
```

[successful css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJRSh.png)

However, I'm finding that with `bslib` themes, I can't use the same method to apply the css.

I've seen these two resources that point to using the `bslib::bs_add_rules` function to solve this:

- https://github.com/rstudio/bslib/issues/360
- [Override DT default selection color when using bslib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67918769/override-dt-default-selection-color-when-using-bslib)

Based on those, I've tried variants of the following, but can't seem to make it work:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- bslib::page_fluid(
  theme = bslib::bs_add_rules(
      bslib::bs_theme(),
      sass::as_sass("table.dataTable tbody tr.selected td {
             color: black !important;
             box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 9999px yellow !important;}"
      )),
  DT::dataTableOutput("test_table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$test_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(iris, selection = 'single')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server = server)
```

[unsuccessful css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qB7LV.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is on the object tag. If you inspect the HTML code you will notice that it should be  `.table.dataTable tbody tr.active td` when you use `sass::as_sass`, not `table.dataTable tbody tr.selected td`

```
library(shiny)

ui <- bslib::page_fluid(
  theme = bslib::bs_add_rules(
    bslib::bs_theme(),
    sass::as_sass("table.dataTable tbody tr.active td {
             color: black !important;
             box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 9999px yellow !important;}"
    )),
  DT::dataTableOutput("test_table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$test_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(iris, selection = 'single')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server = server)
```